# Java 8 map compute with set as value

Tags: java-8

My map looks like this

```
private Map<String, LinkedHashSet<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

in traditional approach I can add value to map with key check as below

```
public void addEdge(String node1, String node2) {
        LinkedHashSet<String> adjacent = map.get(node1);
        if (adjacent == null) {
            adjacent = new LinkedHashSet();
            map.put(node1, adjacent);
        }
        adjacent.add(node2);
    }
```

with java 8, I can do something like this, with this one also I'm getting same output.

```
map.compute(node1, (k,v)-> {
            if(v==null) {
                v=new LinkedHashSet<>();
            }
            v.add(node2);
            return v;
            });
```

is there any better way to do with java 8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java8 functional style, how can i map the values to already existing key value pair](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34021652/in-java8-functional-style-how-can-i-map-the-values-to-already-existing-key-valu)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use

```
map.computeIfAbsent(node1, k -> new LinkedHashSet<>()).add(node2);
```

If `node1` is already found in the map, it will be equivalent to:

```
map.get(node1).add(node2);
```

If `node1` is not already in the map, it will be equivalent to:

```
map.put(node1, new LinkedHashSet<>()).add(node2);
```

This is exactly what you're looking for, and is even described as a use case in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-).

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
map.merge(node1,new LinkedHashSet<>(),(v1,v2)->v1!=null?v1:v2).add(node2);
```

and also

```
map.compute(node1,(k,v)->v!=null?v:new LinkedHashSet<>()).add(node2);
```